# Unitary representation of the loop group LSU(2)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

> Let $\pi$ is a standard representation of G = SU(2) on
>   $\mathbb{C}$$^2$. For every z $\in$ $\mathbb{S}$$^1$, define an
>   irreducible unitary representation $\pi$$_z$ of the loop group LG on
>   $\mathbb{C}$$^2$ by
>
> $\pi$$_z$ (f) = $\pi$(f(z)), f $\in$LG
>
> Show that $\pi$$_z$ and $\pi$$_1$ are not unitarily equivalent for z
>   $\neq$ 1.

This question is from the book: *Kazhdan's Property (T)*, Ex4.4.6, there is a hint to consider their characters.

I do not know much about loop groups, the loop group of G is denoted by LG, it is the continous maps from  $\mathbb{S}$$^1$ to G, maybe not keep the identity element?